# How can I create multiple observations from a single observation (two variables) in SAS

Tags: sas

I would like your help with creating multiple observations from one observation.
How can i get this done?

My data set looks like this.

```
Name | Date       | X_Number | Y_Number |
-----|------------|----------|----------|
John | 01-01-2024 | 646463   |          |
Jane | 14-12-2023 | 456537   | 6384563  |
Jim  | 03-05-2022 | 463940   |          |
```

Desired output

```
Name | Date       | Number  |
-----|------------|---------|
John | 01-01-2024 | 646463  |
Jane | 14-12-2023 | 456537  | 
Jane | 14-12-2023 | 6384563 |
Jim  | 03-05-2022 | 463940  |
```

Any help much appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
data have;
input Name $ Date :ddmmyy10. X_Number Y_Number;
infile datalines missover;
format Date ddmmyy10.;
datalines;                     
John 01-01-2024 646463          
Jane 14-12-2023 456537 6384563  
Jim  03-05-2022 463940          
;

data want;
   set have;
   array n X_Number Y_Number;
   do over n;
      if n ne . then do;
         number = n; output;
      end;
   end;
   keep name date number;
run;
```

Comment: Use `format Date ddmmyyd10.;` to maintain the original flavor of the date value rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Your example loses the *X* and *Y* context of the original values. In many scenarios you want a lossless transformation that maintains a name=value correspondence.

Example:

Proc TRANSPOSE by row

```
data t_view(label='each row has unique key') / view=t_view;
  set have;
  _rownum + 1;
run;

proc transpose
  data=t_view 
  out=want ( rename = (value1=value)
             where  = (not missing(value))
           )
  prefix=value
;
  by _rownum name date ;
  var x_number y_number;
run;
```